# How to find tags inside a class with Beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I tried finding all the `<p>` tags inside the class **content-inner** and I don't want all the the `<p>` tags that talks about copyright (the last `<p>` tags outside the container class) to appears when filtering the `<p>` tags and my images shows an empty list or nothing comes out at all and therefore no image is been saved.

```py
main = requests.get('https://url_on_html.com/')
beautify = BeautifulSoup(main.content,'html5lib')

news = beautify.find_all('div', {'class','jeg_block_container'})
arti = []

for each in news:
    title = each.find('h3', {'class','jeg_post_title'}).text
    lnk = each.a.get('href')
    r = requests.get(lnk)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html5lib')
    content = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all('p')]
    content = ' '.join(content)
    images = [i['src'] for i in soup.find_all('img')]

    arti.append({
        'Headline': title,
        'Link': lnk,
        'image': images,
        'content': content
    })
```

This website HTML looks like this:

```html
<html><head><title>The simple's story</title></head>
<body>
    <div class="content-inner "><div class="addtoany_share_save_cont"><p>He added: “The President king  administration has embarked on 
    railway construction</p>
    <p>Once upon a time there were three little sisters, and their names were and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>
        <script></script>
    <p> we will not once in Once upon a time there were three little sisters, and their names were and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>
    <p>the emergency of our matter is Once upon a time there were three little sisters, and their names were and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>
    
    <script></script>
    <br></br>
    <script></script>
    <p>king of our Once upon a time there were three little sisters, and their names were and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>
    <script></script>
    <img src="image.png">
    <p>he is our Once upon a time there were three little sisters, and their names were and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>
    <p>some weas Once upon a time there were three little sisters, and their names were and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<p>Copyright © 2021. All Rights Reserved. Vintage Press Limited.  Optimized by <a href="https://inerd360.com/">iNERD360</a></p>
</div>
```

This will show an empty list:

```py
content = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all('div', {'class', 'content-inner'}]
```

As well as for the images this code shows an empty pages too:

```py
images = [i['src'] for i in soup.find_all('img',)]
```

This will filter all `<p>` tags in the HTML page and this is what I don't want

```py
content = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all('p')]
```

How do I filter all the `<p>` tags except the last `<p>` tags outside the class? Also, how do I filter images correctly with `bs4`?

Comment: am waiting someone should please help out

Comment: dear @CygnusX please how do i solve this problem here. how do i eliminate this outer p tags

Comment: Could you provide the link to the website?z

Comment: hi@JacobLee please this is the link view-source:https://thenationonlineng.net/work-on-lagos-calabar-railway-to-start-this-year-amaechi/

Comment: am trying to scrap that page and the paragraph with copyright is disturbing and no image is appearing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace: `content = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all('p')]`

With:

```py
div_list = [div for div in soup.find_all('div', class_="content-inner")]
p_list = [div.find_all('p') for div in div_list]
content = [item.text.strip() for p in p_list for item in p]
```

Leave the rest of the code unchanged.
This way, your script returns a list containing everything you ask for (including images), except adds and copyright string.

Comment: this will insert adds and other strings and this will not be professional___ imaging people ads code showing on your news

Comment: That would have useful to know before. See updated answer following your comment that outputs the desired result.

Comment: thanks so much @Laurent, This resolved the copyright issue but i got errors for the images or a new exception     if file and not file._committed:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_committed' and i try using a forloop and it didnt still work. thanks for resolving my copyright

Comment: This seems to be a separate issue related to another part of your code, can't help here, sorry.

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. If you wish, you can also add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle. In any case, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of all paragraphs

```
paragraphs = soup.find_all("p")
```

Produce a filtered list (list comprehension) of paragraphs **not** starting with the string "Copyright":

```
paragraphs = [item.text.strip() for item in paragraphs if not item.text.startswith("Copyright")]
```

Comment: thanks much @anonymous but images are not working

Comment: sorry all the suggestions and answers here did not work